# Problems with VLC dll library compiling

Tags: .net, vb.net, libvlc

I'm developing a desktop program where I use VLC libraries, but when I compile the code on Visual Studio .NET and I try to execute the binary on a clean Windows installation it does not work and give me this error message:

> Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are missing some DLL's or maybe you need to add some lib / include files.